# How do you take the conjugate of a real matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, real-numbers

I've only seen resources pointing to how to take the conjugate of a complex matrix but how do you take the conjugate of a real matrix?

Let's take this matrix as an example: 
0   1 
1   0

Comment: What is conjugate of a complex number?

Comment: From what I remember, you flip the sign of the imaginary part of the complex number. @cosmo5

Comment: Oh, why is it equal to the transpose? How did you determine that? I'm new to linear algebra... @DanielHuff

Comment: It is not equal to the transpose, sorry. When you conjugate a real matrix you get the same matrix because when you flip the sign of the imaginary part (zero) you still get zero...

Comment: @DanielHuff Interesting... So the conjugate of a matrix only inverts the sign of an imaginary part if there such a part in the matrix right?

Comment: yes, you can interpret it like that